# Winforms C# Disable/ Enable Button on Treenode Click

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, button

I have a treenode which displays a checklist from a SQL database. I have a method to get the selected workflows.

I want to enable the run button if a checkbox is checked and disable the button if nothing is checked and on load.

I'm not sure where to put this if statement. I have tried putting it under the run button on the click action but it is not working correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

```
List<WorkflowViewModel> workflowViewList = new List<WorkflowViewModel();

var workflowList = GetSelectedWrokflows();
if (workflowList.Count == 0)
{

    button.enabled = false;
}
else
{
    button.enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably putting if statement at line 20 will do the job. Without seeing your code I cannot tell more precisely

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy It should be at line 5, outside the class. and after the namespace.

Comment: You should code the `AfterCheck` event, do all tests and then set the Button state.

Comment: Why tag this question with `sql`?

Comment: _I'm not sure where to put this if statement_ Into a function. Where should you call the function? In the AfterCheck  event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a method that will do the work of determining the selected workflow items and enabling or disabling the button. By putting the code in a single method, it allows you to call it from multiple places, and if you need to change the behavior, you only have one place to make the modifications.

Then you can just call this method from the `Form_Load` event, and from the checked list box's `ItemCheck` event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<WorkflowViewModel> workflowViewList = new List<WorkflowViewModel>();

    private void SetRunButtonState()
    {
        workflowViewList = GetSelectedWorkflows();
        button.Enabled = workflowViewList.Count > 0;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetRunButtonState();
    }

    private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        SetRunButtonState();
    }

    // Rest of class code omitted...
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. I added this code but now the button stays disabled even after the checkboxes are selected.. Have you any idea why?

Comment: Oops, I read "display a check list" in the question and used the wrong control. I've switched the code to use a `TreeView` instead. Is that the control you're using?

Comment: I made that change and still not working. 

the button remains disabled even after checking the box

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the call to `SetRunButtonState` in the `treeView1_AfterCheck` event handler, and then use `F11` to step through the code. Most likely there is an issue with the `GetSelectedWorkflows` method, and it's not populating the `workflowViewList` with anything...

Comment: the list is being populated. i switched to if statement and debugged it and found it was skipping the else in the if statement ..why would this happen?

Comment: When you're debugging and exection gets to the `if` statement, check the `Count` property of the workflowViewList. the only reason the `else` would be skipped is if the condition in the `if` evaluated to `true`.